# Sooner or earlier or both?

Tags: grammar

I know similar questions may have been asked, but I believe each question has its own merits and explnation for the asker.

If I have joined a team a while ago, is it correct to say, "I think I should have joined you sooner" or I should use "earlier"?

To my ears both sound OK, earlier and sooner.

Comment: _Sooner_ is fine.

Comment: *Earlier* is preferred in some contexts - you talk about *earlier in the day* not sooner in the day - but here either seems OK.

Comment: Yes, I had this reasoning in my mind too, and I wanted to make sure. Thank you.